# KO databind to array without foreach?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm using MVC + Razor and where possible would like to stay in the strong typed world.

Hence hoping to iterate through my view model using Razor syntax, and data-bind to knockout via the array index.

Is this doable? All the examples I have seen so far preclude the use of the `for-each` template.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(_ => _[i],new {@readonly = "readonly", data_bind = string.Format("value:[{0}]",i) });
```

Where the strongly typed model is an array, and the above is being iterated over from inside a for loop.

Comment: for-each is over the *collection* (i.e. array, which may be empty), but each [nested] data-bind is to the the item properties, so each "same" text box (for each item) should bind to the same property name. Otherwise, you lost me.

Comment: @pst is correct.  Also, you would need to setup your Knockout view model with these properties before you could bind to them.

Comment: @Ek0nomik It appears the latest ko/ko.mapping binds to non-existant properties (it creates an observable for them), so it's only the structure (i.e. object hierarchy) that needs to exist .. It Works Here (TM), and we use it for a WS/XML-driven model. YMMV as the documentation seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: I wanna avoid doing for-each on the client side. I just want to print the entire html and bind the KO member. Is this doable without the ko-foreach?

Comment: Of course that you can bind to an array without the foreach. http://jsfiddle.net/8pVEr/ If it is not working then your binding syntax is probably wrong. But it is hard to help in that without seeing how your view and ko viewmodel looks like...

Comment: @nemesv Looking to make this work... http://jsfiddle.net/8pVEr/

Comment: @nemesv http://jsfiddle.net/8pVEr/1/ Woops try this one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow this works thanks to @nemesv for the original jsfiddle:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $data[0].name"></input>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $data[1].name"></input>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $data[2].name"></input>
```

With the following javascript file.

```
var ViewModel = ko.observableArray( [{
        name: 'name1'
    }, {
        name: 'name2'
    }, {
        name: 'name3'
    }]
);

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

The **$data** is required without it, it doesn't work. I'm still not sure why this is.

http://jsfiddle.net/8pVEr/3/